# Why is ImageStat returning incorrect statistics for signed integer images (`mode='I'`)?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have depth images with very large ranges of values, on the order of [0, 10,000], saved as pngs. These are loaded by default as PIL Images with [`mode='I'`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes), 32-bit signed integer pixels, but have some unexpected behavior.

For example, [`Image.show()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show) displays a blank white screen. This is somewhat expected as I would guess the function is expecting input either [0, 1] or [0, 255] and is truncating the pixel values in my images that are outside that range.

More worryingly, [`ImageStat`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageStat.html) is returning an incorrect values for most statistics. I have confirmed both these values with independently obtained results from `numpy` and Matlab. This doesn't happen for more conventional RGB images, `mode='RGB'`.

## Question

What's going on here? Is this also a truncation issue?

## MCVE

Use the following image as `test.png`

[image: Depth camera capture with smoothing]

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("test.png")
im.show() # shows white blank screen 
print(im.mode) # prints 'I'

from PIL.ImageStat import Stat
stat = Stat(im)
print(stat.mean)    # [85.10539415869734]
print(stat.extrema) # [(0, 255)]
print(stat.sum)     # [32927277.0]

import numpy as np
print(np.mean(im)) # 28051.3720754717
print(np.min(im))  # 9992
print(np.max(im))  # 63816
print(np.sum(im))  # 10853075856
```

Matlab's results are similar to numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Image.show()` displays a blank white screen

The reason for this is because `Image.show()` uses a temporary buffer to store the image object. And then converts the Image object to `.bmp` (**bitmap**) before displaying it. Bitmap format does not support 32 bit single channel images (greyscale), therefore the results obtained via `show()` are undesirable.

> `ImageStat` is returning an incorrect values for most statistics

Upon doing Source Code Analysis of `ImageStat` module, i came to know that the module is specifically built to deal with images having **0 ≤ *sample space* > 256**, or images having pixel values in the range **(0 ≤ value ≤ 255)**.

For example, If we analyse the `Stat.extreme`:-

```
def _getextrema(self):
    """Get min/max values for each band in the image"""

    def minmax(histogram):
        n = 255
        x = 0
        for i in range(256):
            if histogram[i]:
                n = min(n, i)
                x = max(x, i)
        return n, x  # returns (255, 0) if there's no data in the histogram

    v = []
    for i in range(0, len(self.h), 256):
        v.append(minmax(self.h[i:]))
    return v
```

we can clearly see, that the the function used to calculate the *upper and lower bound* of image's pixel values can't return a value lower then 0, nor can it return a value greater then 255. i.e **(value ∈ {0 - 255})**.

The `Stat` function is made in such a way, that it only works properly if range of image's pixel values are under 256.

> Is this also a truncation issue

No. Truncation does not happen, during the calculation of values in `Stat`. The `Stat` module isn't made in a way that it should be able to flatten out/truncate pixel values out of its normal range. Rather what happens is, when an image object is passed to `Stat` it just does normal calculation on it (assuming the range of pixels value is between 0 to 255). Then the output solely depends on whether the input parameter caused interruption/exception in value calculation or not i.e. if everything somehow goes right, the the output will be undesirable. But this isn't always true.

**For Example:-**

```
img = Image.new("I", (300, 300), (3000))

stat = Stat(img)
print(stat.mean)
print(stat.extrema)
print(stat.sum)
```

**Code Upon Execution:-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vasu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/PIL/testing.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(stat.mean)
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageStat.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    v = getattr(self, "_get" + id)()
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageStat.py", line 104, in _getmean
    v.append(self.sum[i] / self.count[i])
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Therefore, the output would either be undesirable or would eventually lead to an error/exception.

> Does that mean `PIL` doesn't support `I` color mode

No. `PIL` has full support for 32 bit signed integers.

For Example, if we try to obtain pixel values of the your image:-

```
im = Image.open(r"Input_img")
im = list(im.getdata())

print(im)
```

We get the actual pixel values:-

```
40384, 40384, 40384, 40384, 40384, 40600, 40600, 40600, 40808, 41016, 41232, 41440, 41656.....22232]
```

**CONCLUSION:-** `PIL` has native support for 32 bit signed integer pixels, but `ImageStat` does not.

**P.S.:-** The current state of **PIL/pillow** documentation is not that good, i.e. it is not that good at explaining.....whatever it is trying to explain. Therefore, we should add more intel to it as much as possible. So, I would suggest you to post an issue/pull request on [PIL repository on Github](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/), regarding improvements in description of `ImageStat` module. Like adding lines such as:-

> Module does not have a native support for pixel values greater then 8 bits

or something else along those lines.